# Postgres : how to join tables from json list items

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Assuming I've a json column "my_json" in a psql table "A":

```
['key_A', 'key_B', 'key_C']
```

and a table B with records

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| key_A | value_A |
| key_B | value_B |
| key_C | value_C |

, how can I join those 2 tables ? I tried

```
select 
jsonb_array_elements_text(my_json) as key, BT.value 
from A as AT
inner join B as BT
on AT.key = BT.id
```

but it does not work errror : column AT.key does not exists

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `json_array_elements` function.

```
SELECT *
FROM json_array_elements('["A", "B", "C"]')
```

If your situation want to get an array from columns of tables you can try this query below

```
SELECT value
FROM T CROSS JOIN lateral json_array_elements(col) v
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7078b577e2a6802f9520459cf4f08d3b)

**EDIT**

I saw you modify your question, You can try to use `json_array_elements_text` get values from your array data from JSON , then do `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM A a
CROSS JOIN lateral json_array_elements_text(a.col) v
INNER JOIN B b ON v.value = b.ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=afa77cf0854cf8f7cd007cc8a3796384)

Comment: thx for your quick answer but sorry , I edited my question. I found the json_array_element statement but still got issue when trying to join to another table

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNET I see I edit my answer hope that can help you